# Joining tables where attributes match In a range

Tags: sql, db2

Hello I have a query i want to set up for a database that involves items,costs and weight

Say the table for the items with their respective weights looks like this called `ItemWeight`

```
NAME      Weight
--------  -------
item1     250
item2     1600
item3     2200
```

And another table for the costs of items that are in a range of weight that looks like this
`CostPerWeight`

```
Weight    Cost
--------  ------
2500      6.00
2000      5.75
1500      5.00
1000      3.00
500       2.00
```

So the resultant table i want to be able to pull is one with the item, its weight and its cost.

So far i've put together:

```
SELECT I.NAME, I.weight, C.cost
FROM ItemWeight I 
JOIN CostPerWeight C ON I.Weight <= C.Weight
```

But the problem is an item that is say 265 in weight should be 2.00 in cost because it is less than 500 but it is also less than 1500 which is 5.00 in cost so I just need help to find a way to check if an attribute is within a range of another attribute to get my desired result. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You say "less than", but your query says "less than or equal".  If the item weighs 500, is it `2.00` or `3.00`?  (My personal preference is for `3.00`, because then it's a nice exclusive upper bound)  This is one of those situations where a derived column/table/materialized view with the inclusive-lower/exclusive-upper for the range is really handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions would be to aggregate:

```
SELECT I.NAME, I.Weight, MIN(C.Cost) AS Cost
FROM ItemWeight I 
JOIN CostPerWeight C ON I.Weight <= C.Weight
GROUP BY I.NAME, I.Weight;
```

Comment: what does the group by 1,2 do exactly? because i tried this and it gave me an error saying that the statements i have in the select clause are not in the group by clause

Comment: instead of numbers, have the fields then (edited answer, in some SQL languages you can reference fields by their number of ordering in the SELECT.

More on GROUP BY and aggregations here - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the correct row in the `cost` table:

```
select i.*, c.cost
  from ItemWeight i
  left join CostPerWeight c on c.weight =
    (select min(d.weight) from CostPerWeight d where d.weight >= i.weight)
```

Also, you don't define what happens if an item has a weight higher than 2500. For clarity, in the table `CostPerWeight` would rename the column `weight` to `up_to_weight`.

Comment: Yes that is a good suggestion for the renaming, also i tried this query and it gave me an error saying that cost is undefined name, i believe it is referring to the part in the query where it says "from cost where weight"

Comment: Fixed. Try again.